# DynamoDB session state provider throws errors to application

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, session-state, amazon-dynamodb

I run a ASP.NET webservice using DynamoDB in AmazonWebServices for sessionstate handling.

However today I get loads of exception bubbling up to application level on errors. Are anyone else experience these errors. I had this behavior the other week as well and it lasted about 1-2 h and then went away.

I use it exactly as described here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsNET/latest/DeveloperGuide/net-dg-dynamodb-session.html

I use version 2.3.0.1 of the AWS Sessionstate provider (from the AWS SDK)

This is the stack trace:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpRequest.GetResponse()
```

Any ideas?

Edit:
Suitable parts from Web.config upon request

```
<appSettings>      
  <add key="AWSAccessKey" value="XXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
  <add key="AWSSecretKey" value="XXXXXXXXXXXX"/>        
</appSettings>

<compilation>
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="AWS.SessionProvider, Version=2.3.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9f476d3089b52be3" />
    <add assembly="AWSSDK, Version=2.3.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9f476d3089b52be3" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>

<system.web>
  <sessionState timeout="20" mode="Custom" customProvider="DynamoDBSessionStoreProvider">
    <providers>
      <add name="DynamoDBSessionStoreProvider" type="Amazon.SessionProvider.DynamoDBSessionStateStore" Region="eu-west-1" />
    </providers>
  </sessionState>  
</system.web>
```

Edit2:
I do see a lot of throttled requests appering at the same time as the errors started, even thou I dont seem to be even close on the provisioned thruput. However during the time I see a slight decline in traffic in the monitoring for the ElasticLoadBalancer (as expected towards end of business day). So it doesnt feel like I am getting a lot more hits and therefor getting throttled requests.

Screendump of dynamodb monitoring
http://1drv.ms/1vU7BzO

Comment: Your question should include more details to let us help you.  Can you provide us with a code sample for example ? How did you configure your Access Key, Secret Key ? etc ...

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be one of the following, since it appears it works most of the time, occasionally has problems, and then recovers without you doing anything:

- You exceeded your rate request that you provisioned when you setup
  the DB - that will throw a 400 error (this is my first guess)
- make sure the time on your IIS is in sync with AWS; this may cause signature problems
- make sure you are not trying to exceed the max size of 64KB for a single item.

Comment: I've added some monitoring dumps from dynamodb, I do see a lot of throttled requests, however the incoming traffic to the site is not higher during the errors so I dont understand where all of these throttled requests come from. (My traffic is around 2000 hits per 5 min, but I have >3000 throttled requests, and a lot of traffic is unaffected)